# What's the standard algorithm for syncing two lists of related objects?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, list, synchronization

I'm pretty sure this must be in some kind of text book (or more likely in all of them) but I seem to be using the wrong keywords to search for it... :(

A recurring task I'm facing while programming is that I am dealing with lists of objects from different sources which I need to keep in sync somehow. Typically there's some sort of "master list" e.g. returned by some external API and then a list of objects I create myself each of which corresponds to an object in the master list (think "wrappers" or "adapters" - they typically contain extended information about the external objects specific to my application and/or they simplify access to the external objects).

### Hard characteristics of all instances of the problem:

- the implementation of the master list is hidden from me; its interface is fixed
- the elements in the two lists are not assignment-compatible
- I have full control over the implementation of the slave list
- I cannot control the order of elements in the master list (i.e. it's not sortable)
- the master list does either not provide notification about added or removed elements at all or notification is unreliable, i.e. the sync can only happen on-demand, not live
- simply clearing and rebuilding the slave list from scratch whenever it's needed is not an option:

  - initializing the wrapper objects should be considered expensive
  - other objects will hold references to the wrappers

### Additional characteristics in some instances of the problem:

- elements in the master list can only be identified by reading their properties rather than accessing them directly by index or memory address:

  - after a refresh, the master list might return a completely new set of instances even though they still represent the same information
  - the only interface for accessing elements in the master list might be a sequential enumerator
- most of the time, the order of elements in the master list is stable, i.e. new elements are always added either at the beginning or at the end, never in the middle; however, deletion can usually occur at any position

So how would I typically tackle this? What's the name of the algorithm I should google for?

In the past I have implemented this in various ways (see below for an example) but it always felt like there should be a cleaner and more efficient way, especially one that did not require two iterations (one over each list).

Here's an example approach:

1. Iterate over the master list
2. Look up each item in the "slave list"
3. Add items that do not yet exist
4. Somehow keep track of items that already exist in both lists (e.g. by tagging them or keeping yet another list)
5. When done, iterate over the slave list and remove all objects that have not been tagged (see 4.) and clear the tag again from all others

---

**Update 1**
Thanks for all your responses so far! I will need some time to look at the links.
[...] *(text moved to main body of question)*

**Update 2**
Restructered the middle-paragraph into a (hopefully) more easily parseable bullet lists and incorporated details added later in the first update.

Comment: I don't see how you could do this any other way if the master list doesn't notify you that it's changed...

Comment: The "standard algorithm" is definitely to keep the lists sorted prior to merging.  Barring that, I think you have to do something pretty much like you describe here.

Comment: try googling for "data reconsiliation algorithms"

Answer (score 6):

The 2 typical solutions are:
1. Copy the master list to the sync list.
2. Do an O(N*N) comparison between all element pairs.

You've excluded the smart options already: shared identity, sorting and change notifications.

Note that it's not relevant whether the lists can be sorted in a *meaningful* way, or even completely. For instance, when comparing two string lists, it would be ideal to sort alphabetically. But the list comparison would still be more efficient if you'd sort both lists by string *length*! You'd still have to do a full pairwise comparison of strings of the same length, but that will probably be a much smaller nummber of pairs.

Comment: What do you mean with shared identity? I can't find any reference on google.

Comment: @ÉtienneReinstateMonica: With "identity" I mean the address of an object, or any similar property that exactly identifies an object. In particular, two object expressions denote the same object **if and only if** they resolve to the same identity/address. "Shared" in this context means that the two lists of objects use the same identity property to represent the object on the lists.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like the set reconciliation problem i.e. the problem of synchronizing unordered data. A question on SO was asked on this: [Implementation of set reconciliation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457045/implementation-of-set-reconciliation-algorithm).

Most of the references on google are to technical paper abstracts.

Comment: I think OP is looking to synchronize lists, not sets. Preserving ordering will require a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

Often the best solution to such problems is to not solve them directly.

IF you really can't use a sorted binary searchable container in your part of the code (like a set or even a sorted vector) then...

Are you very memory bound? If not then I'd just create a dictionary (an std::set for example) containing the contents of one of the lists and then just iterate over the second which I want o sync with the first.

This way you're doing n*logn to create the dictionary (or n*X for a hash dictionary depending on which will be more efficient) + m*logn operations to go over the second list and sync it (or just M*Y) - hard to beat if you really have to use lists in the first place - it's also good you do it only once when and if you need it and it's way better then keeping the lists sorted all the time which would be a n^2 task for both of them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a fellow named Michael Heyeck has a good, [O(n) solution](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=2250) to this problem. Check out that blog post for an explanation and some code.

Essentially, the solution tracks both the master and slave lists in a single pass, tracking indices into each. Two data structures are then managed: a list of insertions to be replayed on the slave list, and a list of deletions.

It looks straightforward and also has the benefit of a proof of minimalism, which Heyeck followed up with in a [subsequent post](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=2271). The code snippet in this post is more compact, as well:

```
def sync_ordered_list(a, b):
x = 0; y = 0; i = []; d = []
while (x < len(a)) or (y < len(b)):
    if y >= len(b): d.append(x); x += 1
    elif x >= len(a): i.append((y, b[y])); y += 1
    elif a[x] < b[y]: d.append(x); x += 1
    elif a[x] > b[y]: i.append((y, b[y])); y += 1
    else: x += 1; y += 1
return (i,d)
```

Again, credit to Michael Heyeck.

Comment: The question states the master list is not ordered. So that's a different problem.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, OP is only saying that his master list isn't _sortable_. That is, it's still and ordered list -- just one where OP can't control the ordering. As far as I can tell, Heyeck's solution meets these constraints.

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ STL the algorithm is called set_union. Also, implementing the algorithm is likely to be a lot simpler if you do the union into a 3rd list.

Comment: This will likely just perform the algorithm the OP describes. Also, the OP is looking for a language agnostic solution to this problem, ie: an algorithmic solution.

Comment: @Ben S: the questioner said they were having trouble pulling up algorithms in google... and asked for the name to google for. My answer is a leaping off point for the questioner to narrow their googling.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem in one project in the past.

That project had one master data source and several clients that update the data independently and in the end all of them have to have the latest and unified set of data that is the sum of them.

What I did was building something similar to the SVN protocol, in which every time I wanted to update the master database (which was accessible through a web service) I got the revision number. Updated my local data store to that revision and then commited the entities that aren't covered by any revision number to the database.

Every client has the ability to update it's local data store to the latest revision.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Javascript version of Michael Heyek's python code.

```
    var b= [1,3,8,12,16,19,22,24,26]; // new situation
    var a = [1,2,8,9,19,22,23,26]; // previous situation
    var result = sync_ordered_lists(a,b);
console.log(result);
    function sync_ordered_lists(a,b){
// by Michael Heyeck see http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=2250
// a is the subject list
// b is the target list
// x is the "current position" in the subject list
// y is the "current position" in the target list
// i is the list of inserts
// d is the list of deletes
        var x = 0; 
        var y = 0; 
        var i = []; 
        var d = []; 
        var acc = {}; // object containing inserts and deletes arrays
        while (x < a.length || y < b.length) {
            if (y >= b.length){
                d.push(x); 
                x++;
            } else if (x >= a.length){ 
                i.push([y, b[y]]); 
                y++;
            } else if (a[x] < b[y]){ 
                d.push(x); 
                x++;
            } else if (a[x] > b[y]){ 
                i.push([y, b[y]]); 
                y++;
            } else { 
                x++; y++;
            }
        }
        acc.inserts = i;
        acc.deletes = d;
        return acc;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't match the question at all: For starters, my lists are neither ordered nor type-compatible.

Answer (score -2):

Very brute-force and pure technical approach:

Inherit from your List class (sorry don't know what is your language). Override add/remove methods in your child list class. Use your class instead of the base one. Now you can track changes with your own methods and synchronize lists on-line.

Comment: The master list is accessible for instance only through a third-party web-service, the code called to change the master-list cannot be changed.